# requiring angular modules in browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I have written a module called loginModule found in loginModule.js file.

```
var loginModule = angular.module('loginModule', []);

loginModule.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
       $scope.userName = "Stack Overflow";
    });
});
```

And I have another module called root module which depends on loginModule, so as browserify suggests, I have required it in rootModule.js file.

```
require('./modules/loginModule.js');

var rootModule = angular.module('rootModule', ['ngRoute','loginModule']);

rootModule.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.sample = "Hello angular";
});
```

Directory Structure

```
| app  
| - modules  
| | - loginModule.js  
| - rootModule.js  
| gulpfile.js
```

But when I my gulp task tries to bundle them, I keep getting this error message.

[image: Error message when including angular modules]

If what I have understood is correct, bundling just concats the JavaScript files to make one huge JS file (usually referred to as bundle.js), and the files to be concatenated and the dependencies are resolved by going through the require('*.js') statements found in the entry point file. (Here rootModule.js).

So am I doing everything correctly here? Any suggestions guys? I know I am missing something very basic...

Answer (score 0):

Just found an issue for your same problem on github, [here](https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/225).
The issue is still open. Still, the last post says:

```
I was able to get it to work after installing a fresh node and npm, and reinstalling all my node_modules again.
```

So, if your're using `nodejs 4.1`, `npm@3`, you could try to upgrade, too... :-)